# Evaluate $\prod_p \frac{p^s-1}{p^s-p}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluate $\displaystyle\prod_{p\in prime} \frac{p^s-1}{p^s-p}$

I arrived at this expression after realising that the exponent of p-adic valuation is a multiplicative function, so I built an Euler product for $$\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}\frac{p^{v_p(n)}}{n^s}$$

Then I took a product over all primes yielding a function containing the given expression.

Since this product divides out every prime in turn from $\zeta(1)$, in theory leaving $\zeta(0)$, I thought it might reveal something about $\zeta(0)=\sum\frac1{n^0}$.  Initially I thought it would equal $\dfrac{\zeta(0)}{\zeta(s)}$; at least in some regions of $\mathbb{C}$

But then I struggled to work out how to multiply out the product and it turns out I overlooked some convergence issues.

There have been some helpful comments and an answer which I need to spend a bit of time with.

Comment: How did you come to this divergent product and $\zeta(0),\zeta(s)$ ? How do you **prove** $\zeta(s)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} = \prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$ **for** $ \Re(s) > 1$, more generally the Euler product for multiplicative Dirichlet series ?

Comment: @reuns I came to it by constructing an Euler product which eliminates individual primes. I can see the $\zeta(0)$ I'm using is divergent, which is the likely problem. As for the proof... are you saying I need to look closer at that to see why my identity isn't valid, or are you saying look at that to find out where it converges? At the moment I'm trying to determine whether it's convergent **somewhere**.

Comment: Can you prove that $\prod_p (1+p^{-s})$ and $\prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}=\prod_p (1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty p^{-sk})$ converge for $\Re(s) > 1$ ? Let $\prod_{p \le m} \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_m(n) n^{-s}$. What are the coefficients $a_m(n)$ ?

Comment: Your product is a nonsense, infinite products are of the form $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+a_n)$ where $a_n \to 0$ which converges iff $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(1+a_n)$ converges. Thus the question is if you understand the Euler product of $\zeta(s)$ and what it implies. In particular, can you find the coefs $a_m(n)$ I mentioned ?

Comment: @reuns I'm sorry, there was a critical error in the question. It was meant to say $\dfrac{p^s-1}{p^s-p}$. Would your critique that it is nonsense still stand?

Comment: Sure. Did I say infinite products are of the form $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+a_n)$ with $a_n \to 0$ ? Did I say that $\zeta(s) = \prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$  for $\Re(s) > 1$ ?

Comment: @reuns My current working hypothesis is that Daniel seems to have made some sense out of it in his answer below (at least now I corrected my initial error); is there any reason not to believe that?  Furthermore; my $\zeta(0)/\zeta(s)$ question I suggested could possibly be interpreted to be true if we analytically continued the function to $s=1$.

Comment: Daniel first step was to make $1+a_n$ clear so that convergence is obvious. For now analytic continuation is not of your level (did you work on $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n = \frac{1}{1-z}$ ?)

Comment: @reuns not just yet. I'm busy with algebra relating $\zeta(4)$ just now to $\zeta(4-1)$ so as to understand the impediments better.

Comment: If you meant $F(s)=\sum_{n\in\Bbb N}\frac{p^{v_p(n)}}{n^s}$ then $F(s) =\frac{1}{1-p^{1-s}} \prod_{q \ne p} \frac{1}{1-q^{-s}} = \frac{1-p^{-s}}{1-p^{1-s}} \zeta(s)$

Comment: @reuns yes, that's what I meant and yes, your product appears to correspond with what Daniel put so that makes sense too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write it in the form

$$\prod_p \frac{1 - p^{-s}}{1 - p^{-(s-1)}}.$$

Knowing the Euler product of the $\zeta$ function, we can immediately read off that for $\operatorname{Re} s > 2$ the product converges to

$$\frac{\zeta(s-1)}{\zeta(s)}.$$

Writing the factors in the form

$$1 + \frac{1 - p^{-1}}{p^{s-1}-1},$$

we can see that $\operatorname{Re} s > 1$ is a necessary condition for the convergence of the product. But for $\operatorname{Re} s > 1$, the product of the numerators $1-p^{-s}$ converges absolutely, hence the total product converges there only when

$$\prod_p \frac{1}{1 - p^{-(s-1)}}$$

converges, which means the product converges at $s$ if and only if the Euler product of $\zeta$ converges at $s-1$, so overall the product converges on the set $\{ s : \operatorname{Re} s \geqslant 2, s \neq 2\}$.

Comment: And for the convergence of $\prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$ ie. of $\sum_p p^{-s}$ at $s= 1+it$ we need the prime number theorem even if the Mertens theorem shows $\sum_{n \ge 2} \frac{1_{n \in \mathcal{P}}}{n}-\frac{1}{\log n}$ converges

Comment: Thanks a million; plenty of food for thought. The only issue with this answer is that I have it converging to zero at $s=\frac{1}{2}$ because the circumstances just happen to be right for it to equal the product of the negative inverses of the square roots of the primes; which I found interesting. This is an Euler product I've never seen elsewhere.

Comment: @RobertFrost Ah, technicalities. In complex analysis, we say an infinite product converges if a) only finitely many terms are zero, and b) the sequence of partial products of the nonzero terms converges to some $z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$. Thus for $s = 1/2$ the product _diverges_ to $0$ (similarly for $s = 0$ where infinitely many [all] factors are $0$) in this terminology. The reason that we make these restrictions is that we want to have a nice theory for products of holomorphic functions.

Comment: @DanielFischer ah ok thanks. Makes me think one could never use multiplicative functions to understand nontrivial zeroes of zeta function since even if said fns indicate zeta=0 they are considered to diverge so it wouldn't count.